# Android ADT 21 Juno blocking launche application

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, adt

I had recently installing ADT 21 in Eclipse Mobile , but when I launch my application Eclipse was blocked in 100% (progress view) but don't start in AVD ..... I tried to change setting of my app in :

Run as > target > defining my AVD .... but it always Eclipse blocked .

have you any help .

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried with restarting Eclipse?

Comment: Sometimes restarting Eclipse from commandline with clean parameter helps. $ eclipse -clean

Comment: Yes of course I restarted Eclipse maybe 20 times , so that's why I search a logical raison of this problem !